# How to perform AFHTTPRequestOperation in AFNetworking 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, afnetworking-3

I've implemented the JSON parsing using `AFNetworking` many time in some previous apps as:

```
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?get_all_data", BaseURLString];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
//performing parsing here

     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
//error message displayed here
}
```

But as of today I started working on an app after a while I came to use `AFNetworking` again and I installed in using `pods` so as I write this same code as I use to write before it gives me the error saying `Unknown Receiver AFHTTPRequestOperation. Do you mean AFHTTPRequestSerializer?`
After searching about it I found that it's `AFNetworking 2` or `3` era now and they have somehow changed the scenerio. I didn't find the exact solution on how to implement it now. So can anyone write the code in the answer below that works with the latest version of `AFNetworking`.

Comment: as from version 3.x afnetwroking uses its own queue to manage operations, so you don't need to use `AFHTTPRequestOperation` you can call ws as  @MedAmine.Rihane post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the new approach of `AFNetworking 3.x` to parse data:

```
NSString *path = @"yourapilink";
NSString *escapedPath = [path stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

[manager GET:escapedPath  parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

**Hope it help !**